# Same random numbers generated each time

Tags: vb.net

Sorry this will probably sound really stupid and is probably answered somewhere but I can't find it and I'm seriously stuck,
I'm trying to make a dice for a snakes and ladders game and I've got it to work ish except it displays the same pattern of numbers every time I reload the game. It goes 5,4,4,2,3,5,1.... exactly the same each time.

I had it like this:

```
Dim n As Integer = (1 + Rnd() * 5)
```

Then I tried changing it to this:

```
Dim n As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd())) + 1
```

But I still got the exact same numbers

Comment: [Randomize Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zedbtdt(v=vs.90).aspx) They hide the answers to many problem on MSDN

Comment: Check what Rnd() function outputs, does it have params? usually you need a range for a random generator.
Second, following the basic rules of Algebra 6 - 1 + 1 is nonsense because you're adding and subtracting a constant (just leave it as (6)).

Comment: Don't use `Randomize` and `Rnd` at all.  We're not in VB6 anymore Toto.  Create a single instance of the `Random` class and call its `Next` method each time you need a random number.  That's it, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Randomize() initializes the first seed of Rnd(). If you won't use it - VB.NET will use the default seed number.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Random` class.  It is in the `System` namespace.

```
dim random as Random = new Random();
dim randomNumber as int = random.Next();
```

There are overloads of the `Next` method so you can easily restrict the range of returned results.